# Code block in computer programming

Tags: programming-languages

1. What is code block?
2. Is code block can include any number and kind of statement like compound(if,for,while,function,class), assignment?
3. Is each code block have own separate scope?

Comment: Are you asking about code blocks in a specific language? Different languages may have different answers to this question.

Comment: @Venantius How about in python, C#and C++? What is difference between these languages?

Answer (score 0):

1. A code block is a list of statements.
2. No, a code block cannot include a loop or function declaration.  A function or loop will start a new scope and likely a new code block.
3. All statements in a code block are in the same scope.  However, each code block does not necessarily have it's own scope. For example:

   ```
   //OUTTER SCOPE

   variable a;    // code block 1
   statement a;   // code block 1

   loop ( condition ) {

     // INNER SCOPE 

     variable b;                   // code block 2
     statement b;                  // code block 2

   }

   // BACK IN OUTTER SCOPE

   statement c;                  // code block 3
   CAN reference variable a;     // code block 3
   CANNOT reference variable b;  // code block 3
   ```

Code block 1 and 3 are in the same scope, but code block 2 has it's own narrower scope.  There might be some variance language to language, but I think this is generally true.